# Surround Selected Text in Vim Script

Tags: vim

I want to visually select the text
Blah Blah
and prepend it "\textit{"
and append it with "}"

Answer (score 0):

The following line in your Vim configuration will bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> key combination to replace visually selected `text` with `\textit{text}`:

```
vnoremap <C-I> c\textit{<Esc>pa}<Esc>
```

To make it work only in **tex** files, use:

```
autocmd FileType tex vnoremap <C-I> c\textit{<Esc>pa}<Esc>
```

Keep in mind that every use of this binding will **overwrite** your unnamed register with `text`!

**---- EDIT ----**

It is rather rational to leave unnamed register unchanged for our needs by using some other register (X stands for name of register you want to write to):

```
vnoremap <C-I> "Xc\textit{<Esc>"Xpa}<Esc>
```